# in python , why is there a difference in exception when signal handling is done before and after "try except"

Tags: python, signals, try-except

I recently started with python . I was playing with handling the keyboard interrupt , when I came across this behavior

```
import signal,sys

def handleInt(sign,no):
    print "interrupted"

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,handleInt)    # exception raised is IOError

try:
    sys.stdin.read(1)
except IOError:
    print "io interrupt"
```

but if I change the signal handling to after the try-except

```
import signal,sys

def handleInt(sign,no):
    print "interrupted"

try:
    sys.stdin.read(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "keyboard interrupt"

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,handleInt)    # exception raised is KeyboardInterrupt
```

When I press ctrl+c , there is a difference in the exception in the two cases .So why is this behavior ?

Comment: I have checked this code with a python lint , and it shows no indenting problems

Comment: In the second snippet, the signal handler is installed after the try-except block. Thus I guess it has no effect.

Answer (score 5):

Python has its own built-in singal handler for `SIGINT`. This handler simply raises `KeyboardInterrupt`. In your first code, you replaced the built-in handler with the new handler hence you see this output:

```
$python test_exc.py 
^Cinterrupted
```

Note that `io interrupted` is **not** printed, since no exception was raised. In fact modifying the code to:

```
import signal,sys

def handleInt(sign,no):
    print "interrupted"

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handleInt)    # exception raised is IOError

try:
    sys.stdin.read(1)
except IOError:
    print "io interrupt"
else:
    # else is executed only if no exception was raised
    print "done"
```

You get:

```
$python test_exc.py 
^Cinterrupted

done
```

Note that hitting `Ctrl+C` does *not* block the call to `sys.stdin.read(1)` hence you still have to press some key to let the program continue. Raising an exception inside the signal handler will raise it as if the call to `sys.stdin.read(1)` produced it:

```
import signal,sys

def handleInt(sign,no):
    print "interrupted"
    raise OSError

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handleInt)    # exception raised is IOError

try:
    sys.stdin.read(1)
except IOError:
    print "io interrupt"
else:
    # else is executed only if no exception was raised
    print "done"
```

Sample run:

```
$python test_exc.py 
^Cinterrupted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_exc.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.stdin.read(1)
  File "test_exc.py", line 5, in handleInt
    raise OSError
OSError
```

---

Note: you can access the default signal handler via `signal.default_int_handler`.

Comment: but in my case , "io interrupted " is printed and the statement in else is not

Comment: @karyboy What OS are you using and which python version? I've done my tests with python 2.7.4 on Kubuntu 13.04 (linux kernel: 3.8.0).

Comment: @Bakuriu  I m using ubuntu 12.04 , python 2.7.3

Comment: On Debian 7, kernel 3.2, python 2.7.3 (GCC 4.7.2) I get the same result as Bakuriu. But on Ubuntu 12.04, python 2.7.3 (GCC 4.6.3), I get karyboy's result ("io interrupt" on first script).

Answer (score 1):

When you try and register the signal after the blocking call to `sys.stdin.read`, you never actually get there.

So you get an exception when you hit Ctrl-C which raises a `KeyboardInterrupt` breaks out of the read and is caught by the `try`.

When you actually register the signal handler in the first example something slightly different is happening. The interrupt is being handled by your `handleInt` code.